# how to test APK on various devices

Tags: mobile, apk

I have biult mobile app. I want to test my APK on various devices, to make sure it works on all of them. I have only one mobile phone (Galaxy S), my app works on it.
Is there any various-device-simulator where I can test my app? Or the only way is actually test it on real devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use eclipse for Android Development, the emulator provided by the Android ADT Plugin can help you simulate different devices with difference screen sizes and densities. You can do a quick google search for specs of devices you want, like this link:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/

Attached is a link for details about the emulator in eclipse:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html